# Filter specific records from mysql text query

Tags: mysql, sql, nsregularexpression

I have a very long text file which contains mysql data (insert commands with data). I want to extract specific data based on id (specific insert string). here is the example of my data.

> INSERT INTO `tbl_emp_leave_details` VALUES
> (1405,0,'2020-09-01','2020-09-01',0.5,2,'00:00:00','.5',2,'Some
> Personal work','2020-01-09
> 11:25:26',18,0,0,NULL,NULL,0,0,NULL,''),(4612,1,'2021-05-01','2021-05-01',1,5,'00:00:00','1',-1,'1st
> may was holiday this why this is ignored','2021-07-06
> 10:45:55',1,1,81,'2021-08-01 18:04:59','Approved (Auto
> Query)',1,81,'2021-08-02 18:04:59','Approved (Auto Query)'), and so on

I want to filter based on the second column value. if the second column value is 81.

Comment: When asking SQL questions, a [mcve] is a great start!

Comment: You mean you have a plain text file which contains a long sql command, and you want to extract the string from the file?

Comment: @LizhiLiu yes exactly, not a single string there are multiple. around 38 strings (insert commands with data)

Comment: Execute in temporarily created table (maybe even in temp database). Delete unneeded rows. Re-dump needed rows.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan I think it is no relative to mysql, and you can extract desired value by regular expression.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Akina comment i have resolved it.

1. Created temp table with mysql file
2. and form temp table I updated my original table